# Selenium Grid- Running a test in parallel on IE 11

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, selenium-grid2

1. I want to run my test in parallel on Selenium Grid on IE browser 11.
2. I have one Hub machine(VDI machine) on which i have one node as well.
   Machine 1 , Hub1 and Node1
3. For the second Node i have another VDI machine. 
   Machine 2 and Node2.

4.When i use Machine 1 , Hub1 and Node 1.
I can initiate IE browsers.

5.How ever when i use :-

Machine 1 , Hub1 and Node1
and 
Machine 2 and Node2.

6.I can not initiate IE browser on both machines.

I get the Selenium webdriver error:-
"Protected mode must be set to the same value(enabled or disabled) for all zones."
How should i resolve this. I donot have the rights to change the security of the VDI machines.

Answer (score 0):

"Protected mode must be set to the same value(enabled or disabled) for all zones."

You could follow the steps to make it work.

- In IE, find Internet options and open it.
- Go to the Security tab.
- Set the value of the check box "Enable Protected Mode" to the same value, either checked or unchecked, for each zone.

I've checked this on my VM, it is possible to set the security of IE options.

[image]

Comment: Are we sure that this is the only problem.

Comment: Or we need to put some more capabilities for ie in program

Comment: The error message has told us about the possible main issue. You could have a try and check that if this make the error disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Using selenium 4.1.1

```
InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
ieOptions.ignoreZoomSettings();
ieOptions.introduceFlakinessByIgnoringSecurityDomains();
ieOptions.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);       
ieOptions.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);

RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444"), ieOptions);
setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true); // Use this Capability to ignore protected mode settings
```